# "Палка о двух концах"

Tags: значения, предлоги

Почему в словосочетании *"палка о двух концах"* используется такой странный предлог? Я ещё нашёл *"человек есть животное о двух ногах, лишенное перьев"* Платона. Предлог *о* раньше значил также *с*?

Comment: Еще: "Конь о четырех ногах, да спотыкается".

Comment: кстати это устаревшая языковая конструкция, где О значит не С , а скорее об, как книга о людях. как стол о трех ногах. это уже неипользуемое сочтание в современной речи, где о и об меняются в зависимости от наличия согласной вначале слова

Comment: Действительно, как предлог _о_ в значении _с_ звучит архаично, но это значение _о_ сохранилось и довольно часто встречается в глагольных приставках. Например: озаглавить (что-то будет с заглавием), одарить (будет с дарами), озолотить (будет с золотом). Причем _о_ имеет конотацию, что что-то будет не просто _с_ чем-то, но окружено им со всех сторон или по крайней мере это (добавляемое) будет составлять большую или важную часть того, к чему оно добавлено.

Comment: Кстати, это "о" похоже на английское of. Которое тоже "фольклорно" переходит в o': (первое что подвернулось - http://bottle-o-blues.com )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Да, предлог *о* можно использовать в значении *с*. При этом подразумевается тесная, неотъемлемая принадлежность. Даль пишет:

> С качественными и числительными, объясняет эти принадлежности
>   предмета: с чем. *Храм о золотой главе, о трех главах. Печи о глухих*
>   (герметических) *дверках. Ведь ты не о двух головах. У нас о дышле не
>   ездят, все об оглоблях. Стоит Потап о четырех лапах, из году в год
>   воду пьет* (рассадник).

Однако сейчас такой оборот, за исключением устоявшихся выражений вроде *"палка о двух концах"*, звучит архаично и излишне пафосно для разговорной речи. Он уместен в сказках, легендах и стилизации под них, для придания "фольклорного" колорита.

Comment: Выражение "палка о двух концах" весьма часто применяется в узких кругах, например, в шахматных комментариях, по крайней мере, в устных. Так характеризуют рискованное продолжение игры (начинающееся конкретным ходом), указывая этой присказкой на скрытые негативные его стороны. Здесь смысл близок к "оборотной стороне медали", что может расходиться с этимологией и старой практикой использования данного выражения. Но само по себе оно не забыто.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о предлогах, то важно понимать в каком падеже находится слово:

*Палка (о ком? о чем?) о двух концах.*

Очевидно это предложный падеж, а не творительный для которого бы потребовался предлог "с".

В русском языке предложный падеж исторически использовался для указания места, поэтому нет ничего удивительно в таких конструкциях. Проблема в понимании возникает из-за того, что доступные функции предлога "о" в современном русском языке очень ограничены. Но для формирования предложного падежа можно использовать и другие предлоги, тогда эти фразы будут звучать вполне по-современному:

*Палка при двух концах.*

*Животное на двух ногах.*

и т.д.